# How to separate MongoDB journal

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use NFS as db path for my MongoDB (which I read is not recommended, but a client demands it that way) and I'm having trouble separating the journal files.

How would I do that? I've tried setting the `dbpath` to `/mnt/nfs` and it works, but the journal directory is there as well...

Any hints?

Comment: What's the exact error message? How do you determine that is doesn't work? Did you set the NFS options indicated in the [mongodb documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/): bg, nolock, and noatime?

Comment: There is no error message. Problem is that `journal` directory is on NFS server as well, and it shouldn't be. I want to leave `journal` directory on the local machine, as per documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create a [symbolic link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/) that points to the new mountpoint:

> If your server runs out of disk space for journal files, the server
>   process will exit. By default, mongod creates journal files in a
>   sub-directory of dbpath named journal. You may elect to put the
>   journal files on another storage device using a filesystem mount or a
>   symlink.
>
> Note
>
> If you place the journal files on a separate storage device you will
>   not be able to use a file system snapshot tool to capture a valid
>   snapshot of your data files and journal files.

Updated link about: [Journal files](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/journaling/#journal-files)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a directory on a different partition (instead of a separate partition), you can use a bind mount to get part of an existing mount in another place.

If your journal is located in `/data/mongo_journal` and the desired path is the default - `/var/lib/mongodb/journal`, you can add this to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/data/mongo_journal  /var/lib/mongodb/journal        none    defaults,bind 0 0
```

(It is important to ensure that this happens after the mount of `/data` (or the partition containing it).

(This is useful for cases where the application does not deal with symbolic links or for chroots)

For other Unix-like OSes, similar options exist, they tend to have somewhat different details though.